# NoMethodError, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinxsearch

Здравствуйте. Ребята, не могу понять в чем причина ошибки при реалзиации поиска на Sphinx.
Контроллер:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
authorize_resource class: false
def show
@results = Search.get_results(params[:query], params[:context])
end
end
```

Метод класса:

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
CONTEXTS = ['Questions', 'Answers', 'Comments', 'Users']

def get_results(query, context)
query = ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(query)
klasses = [context.singularize.constantize] if CONTEXTS.include?(context)
@results = ThinkingSphinx.search(query, classes: klasses, order: 'model_order ASC') if query.present?
 end
 end
```

Суть ошибки : NoMethodError in SearchesController#show,

```
undefined method `get_results' for Search(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime):Class
```

после того как в ввел в поле поиска и нажал search.
Только начинающий.. поэтому ошибка может быть и очевиднейшая..но не могу понять.. Может sphinx криво установил.

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вам в ответе совершенно верно указали на одну из ошибок. Исправьте её и обновите вопрос. И впредь старайтесь не ходить сюда, чтобы за вас отладили код, освойте отладчик сами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `self`:

```
def self.get_results(query, context)
    # ...
end
```

И лучше не использовать слова типа `get` или `set`. Вместо них:

```
# как get
def name
    @name
end

# как set
def name=(name)
    @name = name
end
```

Comment: в этом случае падает ошибка в строке модели `query = ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(query)`  - undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @rostov-7 ну это означает, что в тело метода вы "зашли". Вторая ошибка говорит о другом.

Comment: @rostov-7 одно починили, упало другое :)

Comment: @D-side меня минусанули, поэтому не могу теперь написать вам в чате. Напишу тут. Почему меня минусанули? Мне теперь жить тяжело.

Comment: @Colibri пока что единственный, у кого вижу мотив -- у автора вопроса. Мол, ему ответ "не помог".

Comment: @D-side мда. Вот и помогай после. А если я удалю ответ, репутация восстановится?

Comment: @Colibri на этот минус -- да.

Comment: @D-side а автор кстати не может минусовать из-за репутации...

Comment: @Colibri ну, у других какой может быть мотив, мне уже неведомо.

Comment: @D-side ладно, автору я все же ответил, он прочитал. Ответ тогда удалю ради репутации ;)

Comment: @D-side удаление не помогает. Классно.

Comment: ребята, никому минус не ставил:)

Comment: спасибо за помощь.. кажется проблема в другом. в неправильном взаимодейтсвии sphinx c бд.

Comment: Тогда какой идиот мне минус поставил? Мне реально тут жизнь это испортило. Ни хрена теперь сделать не могу.

Comment: @rostov-7 спокойствие, мы уже выяснили, что вы технически не могли этого сделать :)

Comment: @rostov-7 тогда поставьте "+" и отметьте мой ответ как решение, пожалуйста.